3 Single Phase Full Bridge Rectifiers for 3 Phase Rectification
We are trying to get rectified output from a star connected 3-phase generator. Line to neutral voltage is 230Vrms. We have tested using a 4 diode full bridge rectifier between one phase and neutral to get rectified output with a peak of approximately 320-340V across the load. We want to load the generator more evenly and make use of the other phases. My understanding is that a standard 6 diode, 3-phase rectifier will give us a peak output voltage of around 540-560V. We would prefer the lower output voltage so instead, I would like to try using 3, 4-diode bridges between each phase and neutral.

Intuitively it looks to me like that would give a 320-340V output as with the single phase line to neutral option but with less ripple. After various searches I haven't seen this done/recommended anywhere which makes me think there's probably a good reason not to do it (apart from the higher part count and lower output voltage). I'm not so great with simulations but the ones I've tried suggest the output voltage is still likely to peak around 540V. Is my intuition wrong or my simulation? Or both?

How do you end up with 540V, please explain? Each phase has peak of 325V to neutral and you wanted to rectify in reference to neutral.

Note: In the circuits below, all phase sources are 100Vrms.

We would prefer the lower output voltage so instead, I would like to try using 3, 4-diode bridges between each phase and neutral.
Intuitively it looks to me like that would give a 320-340V output as with the single phase line to neutral option but with less ripple.

For this to be true, you assumed that each full bridge conducts with no overlap with other bridges, i.e. if any diodes in a bridge conduct, all other bridges are off. That is only possible when each phase source is floating:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

So, the idea will work if you can get all 3 phases floating relative to one another. That also means that only one secondary phase can be grounded. To do that, you'll need 1:1 isolation transformers on 2 of the 3 phases. Or you'll need a separate transformer to supply your load, with the phases not connected together, i.e. neither star nor delta.
Let's now star-connect the windings, with a common neutral:

simulate this circuit
The rectified voltage is now same as for a 3-phase rectifier:

That's to be expected, since the two circuits are equivalent.

Diodes D7,9,11 are in parallel, as are diodes D8,10,12. Thus we can remove the redundant diodes D9..D12.

Diodes D7, D8 never conduct and can be removed.


We end up with the classic 6-diode 3-phase rectifier.

simulate this circuit

Thank you for this explanation, I thought there might have been something like this going on but couldn't get my head around it. Am I right in thinking that another potential solution could be to use 3 diodes on each line and half-wave rectify everything referenced to neutral? I assume the drawback here would be the irregular current pulses for the generator, is that right?

When I say 3 diodes I mean 1 on each line... (too late to edit my comment)

@Dan All the circuits here can be edited and simulated. They are very much “live”.  Try it!

That won't work the way you want it to - the phases aren't independent. Your only options are going to be to reconfigure the generator - some have a "high voltage" and a "low-voltage" wiring configuration. Put a transformer between the generator and rectifier bridge for the desired voltage conversion. Leave the arrangement that you have while splitting the load across the 3 pairs (this will require all loads floating with respect to one another - no common/ground. However, this might get messy). replace your generator with one of desired voltage.

We would prefer the lower output voltage

What is/are the load that you "prefer" the lower voltage? Assuming your load can accept either voltage, generally, the high voltage is preferred - more efficient, less I^2R losses.

Thank you for your answer. Now it seems we have confirmed the output voltage will indeed be high I am considering rewiring the generator as parallel star configuration which should halve the line to neutral voltage. For context, we are doing some testing on hybrid system design feeding hydro output into the MPPT input of a solar charger/inverter which has a max 500VDC rating. Unfortunately I think this will mean our hydro load controller will need additional ballast load to manage the same power at half the voltage but that isn't the end of the world.

It is standard practice to employ the following methods:
1. Half-wave rectification using three lines, neutral and three diodes.

The half-wave-rectified DC voltage Vdc = 1.17 * phase voltage = 1.17 * 230 = 270 V.
2. Full-wave rectification using three lines and six diodes.

The full-wave-rectified DC voltage Vdc = 1.35 * line voltage = 1.35 * 400 = 540 V.

The topology you are suggesting ( 3 - 4 Diodes Rectifier ) will give exactly same results as three phase   Diode Bridge rectifier.
Please simulate this circuit in LTSpice or any other simulator
